# How to use base classes in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to alter an app I've created so that it is reusable. It's based around a single model which sites using the app will subclass. As it stands, my non-reusable version has the following kind of structure:

```
# models.py
class Document(models.Model):
     contents = models.TextField()
     date = models.DateTimeField()

# views.py
from .models import SiteModel
# ...
class MyView(ListView):
    def some_method(self, list_of_pks):
        model_vals = Document.objects.filter(pk__in = list_of_pks).values()

def perform_action(request):
    obj_pk = request.POST.get('obj_pk')
    obj = Document.objects.filter(pk = obj_pk)

    MySignal.send(sender=Document, instance = obj)

#etc, etc
```

This works well enough. But my use case calls for different types of `Document`, one per site, that will have additional fields that aren't known in advance. Based on reading the documentation on [abstract base classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes), I thought the a reasonable solution would look like:

```
# models.py for the app 
class BaseDocument(models.Model):
    contents = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

# models.py for a hypothetical site using the app
class SiteDocument(myapp.BaseDocument):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    # other site-specific fields
```

What I don't understand is how to then reference the model in the app's `views.py`, `forms.py`, etc. I know `BaseDocument.objects.all()`, for example, won't return anything since it isn't connected to a database. Conversely, I can't have `Document.objects.all()` because `Document` hasn't been created yet and is specific to each site. Is an abstract base class not the correct solution, and if so, what is?

**Edit:**

It looks like using a `OneToOneField` may be best suited to my use case, although it looks like that precludes inheriting methods from the superclass and that `BaseDocument.objects.all()` won't list out all its children.

Alternatively, I was wondering if I could just add a `get_document_model()` method to my abstract base class, in the style of [`get_user_model()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/#get_user_model)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with a solution mentioned in my edit, namely creating a `get_document_model()` method inspired by [`get_user_model()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/#get_user_model). This gives me exactly the desired behavior.

```
# models.py in app1
from django.db import models
from django.apps import apps as django_apps

class BaseDocument(models.Model):
    contents = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def get_document_model():
        # exception handling removed for concision's sake
        return django_apps.get_model(settings.DOCUMENT_MODEL)

# models.py in app2
from django.db import models
from app1.models import BaseDocument

class SiteDocument(BaseDocument):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

Throughout `views.py` and elsewhere, I changed things that would have been of the form `Document.objects.all()` to `BaseDocument().get_document_model().objects.all()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't query your abstract classes directly like that since they won't have managers, only the inherited classes. If you really must do inheritance, you can use a concrete base model and inherit from that at the cost of a join on every query.

Think long and hard about whether this is truly necessary, or if you can represent your data in a more generic way. Models make inheritance seem easy, but they're not magic. There are very real performance and complexity considerations.

It might be as easy as adding a `type` field to your model

```
class Document(models.Model):
    DOCUMENT_TYPES = ['site', 'another', 'whatever']

    document_type = models.CharField(choices=DOCUMENT_TYPES)
    ...
```

For more information about abstract vs concrete classes and querying, visit [How to query abstract-class-based objects in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797982/how-to-query-abstract-class-based-objects-in-django)

Comment: I'm not particularly committed to inheritance or an abstract base class, I just was under the impression that was the appropriate solution. This may be an XY problem, and I'm failing to articulate my use case. The sites using the app will only ever use one `Document`, but we don't know its fields in advance. I guess my question could be rephrased as: how do I refer to model in my app knowing that any given site will be subclassing and extending that model?

Comment: I know I don't need `BaseDocument` to be concrete, so that join does seem unnecessary, could I use a ForeignKey to refer to a possible child, then in `views` do something like `BaseDocument.doc_child.objects.all()`?

Comment: Are the documents in an actual hierarchy or are you just looking for ways to do pseudo-inheritance? Unless you can truly justify it, you probably don't need inheritance at all.

Comment: There's no hierarchy. I just don't know how to make an app that modifies an existing app's model. The existing app makes use of certain known, immutable characteristics of the model, but that's the extent of it.

Comment: You could always create a model with a one-to-one relationship with the existing model, the way django User and UserProfile objects are set up.

Comment: That makes sense, and I think I'll go that route. What exactly makes a OneToOne field distinct from python-like subclassing, though?

Comment: Models are a convenient abstraction but they're still database tables under the hood. A OneToOne relationship is an actual database representation, while abstract or inherited classes are not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124318/discussion-between-hoho-and-soviut).